# Can't write in Memcache using Magento Core Cache

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, memcached

I have a class that loads the `Mage::app()->getCache()`, and call the cache methods.

Well this is working very well for Files. I can load and read. But when I switch to Memcached in `local.xml`, the cache stops working. And I have no errors, no warnings. But updating `Zend_Cache_Core::_options['logging']` to `true`, I see this message:

`WARN (4): Zend_Cache_Core::save() / write_control : written and read data do not match`

IMPORTANT: Frontend and Session cache works like a charm. What could be happening?

EDIT:
I was logging `Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached` and discovered that when I call my save method...

```
$cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
$cache->save('my_value', 'my_id', array(), 3600);
```

...the last one Lifetime was being converted to string. I don't know when it happens in ZF but omitting Lifetime solved my problem:

```
$cache->save('my_value', 'my_id', array());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write control is a method that reads back what it has just written, so that consistency is guaranteed. If the data read back does not match what was written, it will in fact issue a remove request.

This is counterproductive with replicated setups. So if your MemCache instance is replicated (ask your hoster if you don't know), it's possible that the data has not yet arrived at the slave node.

You can turn it off in your local.xml, from the top of my head it's a backend option.